# I already created a mysql database. However, for my future tables that I create, I want to default to INNODB

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

How can default to INNODB for every table to create in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `default_table_type` in the `my.cnf` as such:

```
default_table_type = INNODB
```

Oddly enough, this may not be documented in MySQL's documentation.  I have been using this configuration option for a long time and verified its performance again after not being able to find official reference material.

Answer (score 0):

...be sure to look at innodb_file_per_table as well, by default it's 0 and will create all your tables in one huge datafile that will never go down in size, only up (even if you delete data - it's their design). Only by having your InnoDB tables in separate files can you shrink their sizes by 'optimize table' and such.